# how to recompile Qt statically?

Tags: qt

I searched whole internet for this problem.
I want compile Qt statically to run my program without any DLL.
I read several instructions in the internet.that they all told me sth like this:

cd %qtdir%
configure -static -[other option]

make sub-src

but when I use make in cmd,I get this error :
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

and I tried nmake and mingw32-make too. I don't know in what qt directory I must do this.

I wanna a very simple instruction...

Comment: Babak, are you using mingw or MSVC?

Comment: In that case take into account that you must use the Visual Studio command prompt, which has the correct paths and aliases to the MSVC compiled.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux the default compiler is g++, which provices "make". If you are on Windows, and you want to use "make", you need to install the mingw distribution[1].

As pointed out by Dídac Pérez, if you want to use the MSVC compiler[2], you should use the visual studio command prompt, that sets all the environmental variables for you by calling a bat file.

Therefore the instructions would be:

1. open a visual studio command prompt and navigate to your Qt source
   directory
2. type "make confclean" to remove traces from a previous compilation
3. setup a static configuration, by passing the adequate flag (e.g.:
   "configure -static ")
4. type "nmake" to call the visual studio compiler
5. get a cup of coffee and wait a couple of hours (depending on your
   processor(s) :-))

[1]http://www.mingw.org/

[2]http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads#d-2010-express